# c# открыть файл

Tags: c#

есть listbox в котором отображаются папки (в папках ссылки) при нажатии на кнопку эти ссылки выводятся в другой лист бокс, вопрос как мне открыть эти ссылки как это реализовать ? с помощью каких методов и классов ?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно подписаться на событие `listBox2_Click` (второго листбокса, где ссылки):

```
private void listBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var link = listBox2.SelectedItem as string;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(link))
        Process.Start(link);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1)Ловите событие клика по листбоксу с папками
2)В обработчике узнаете по какой папке был клик
3)Заполняете второй листбокс нужными сслыками

Comment: по обраточику каким методом воспользоваться ?

Comment: Ловить  нужно событие Click